# how automatically redis key generated on my server?

Tags: laravel, redis, jwt, predis, entrust

Laravel Framework 5.4.36

in my server i use the redis server for cache and also use some libraries redis, predis, jwt and zizaco entrus, also see with specific version like bellow in my project `composer.json` file

```
"require": {
   "illuminate/redis": "5.4.*",
   "predis/predis": "^1.1",
   "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*",
   "zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev"
},
```

i attached the screenshot about the fake empty redis key automatically generated and my redis server is going high and i face the issue

[image: 1]

so how can i solve it?

i try to resolve this issue in my code review and i can't not get solution, so i expected what exactly going on this issue, how and when it's created fake redis key with empty data

Comment: They all have the same prefix "pel:" which might be a hint. Also in the screenshot it's not empty data but a PHP serialised empty array which hints that it's coming from PHP code. To properly debug this you probably set up xdebug, clear redis completely and put some breakpoints in your code to see which region those keys get generated in. Also you say you are using laravel 8 but your composer.json is using illuminate/redis 5.4

Comment: yes, it's by mistake the Laravel Framework version is 5.4.36.

thank you apokryfos, i will try with put some breakpoints in my code